# Default value of pasv_address in FTP configuration (vsftp)

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

What is the default value of "pasv_address" in the vsftpd config? Will it be the IP address the client uses to connect to the server?

Comment: `man vsftpd.conf`

Comment: It says the default as "Default: (none - the address is taken from the incoming connected socket)" Does this mean it will take the server IP address the client uses to connect to the FTP server? I'm asking this because if the FTP server is deployed on EC2 then if the client is connecting from another EC2 instance then it uses the private IP address to connect to the FTP server and if the client is not in EC2 instance it will use public IP address. So I want to ensure that it picks whatever IP address client uses.

Comment: Exactly, it has no default value. It's not the address the client uses, it's the address the server is receiving the connection on, a subtle difference. In essence, yes, the pasv_address is indeed the one the client connection came in on, one on the public IP will receive the public IP, a request coming in on the private IP gets that IP. Imagine your server is behind a NAT device, the client will be using the public ip-address of the NAT device, which will be translated and the connection will be to to FTP server's private ip-address. That private ip-address  will be the `pasv_address`.